# git: reset branch swallow up master branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-reset

My git history gets something wrong. One of the branches steal master branch commits when I use some commands below:

```
$ git clone [repo_url]
$ git checkout [branch_A_name]  -- This branch has a commit
$ git reset --soft [revision_hash]   -- same as HEAD~1
$ git add [some_files]
$ git commit
$ git push -f
```

After this, I found some commits that I already merged to master branch is stolen by `branch_A`, which I force-pushed just right before. These diffs are removed from `master`.

Actually, this is not mine. My teammates are in this situation and I heard they haven't used `git rebase`.
They just did `reset - commit - force push` and they saw a messed up tree in their pull request page.

We use bitbucket. Thank you.

Comment: How are `branch_A` and `master` related?  There is nothing at all wrong with the steps you took...assuming this is what you really wanted to do.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As you expected easily, `branch_A` is diverged from `master`. That's all. They aren't tangled anymore.

Comment: Please include branch diagrams for `branch_A` and `master` before and after.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand your teammate probably did

```
git reset  --<probably hard> master
<made changes>
git add <changes>
git commit -m <“message”>
git push -f <whatever>
```

While this process will work in some situations it will not work in others. It’s my guess that your teammate let their branch get out of date by not performing `git pull` on the master or by doing `git remote -v update` to get the latest changes before the push. He then did a `git reset --<whatever>` to update and force pushed the branch. This means that the commit history they pushed diverged from the master in more ways than just the commit they wanted to change and other commits may show up there.

To fix this situation they need to

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout feature branch
git rebase <master or origin/master>
git log 
<check if commits are correct in the log>
git diff --name-only origin/master
<check if only his commit appears>
git push -f origin <branch name>
```

Additionally if you are using Forks on Atlassian there is a potential for another situation - their fork is unsynced. Though Atlassian forks are usually set up to auto-sync, a `git push -f` without specifying the branch name can go rogue between an outdated local repository and a fork. Make sure that the commit history on their master is the same as the one on the main repo and that they unchecked and recheckard the “automatic sync” button in settings. Make sure it says that it was last synced a moment ago. From there they’ll need to update their local and all that good stuff.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no additional commit between local latest and remote. They newly cloned remote and did soft reset just for fixing something. It's not up to date -- as far as I know. But I hope your advice can save someone.